# Grout on floor next to shower pan wet

Tags: leak

My shower is 2 years old. It has an acrylic Pan, tiled wall all the way to the ceiling and frameless glass doors.

About a month ago I started getting moisture on the floor next to the back rear corner of the shower pan. I checked for leaks in the caulking along glass door.  None found. Seems to be just the caulk on the floor tile.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You need to identify where the leak is before we can advise you on how to fix it.  You say you have eliminated the door caulking, Plug the drain and fill the pan and see if the leak occurs. Inspect the pan grouting and caulking for cracks and gaps, Etc.